# Is one Activity = one Context?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am confused to differ between context and activity. what is context anyway? does context belongs to one activity ? will the context change if the activity is changed?

I have a game which has multiple activity. each activity for each part, splashscreen, menu, gamescreen , etc.
The problem is I have one singleton SoundManager which use soundpool as it's sound player. I want to load every sound in splashscreen. But after I think it once again, how about the context?

```
   public void loadSound(Context context, int resId, String name) {
        int id = sounds.load(context, resId, priority)
    }
```

if I load the sounds in SplashScreen Activity, how could I play the sound in GameScreen Activity? different context isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

> On Android, a Context is used for many
>   operations but mostly to load and
>   access resources. This is why all the
>   widgets receive a Context parameter in
>   their constructor. In a regular
>   Android application, you usually have
>   two kinds of Context, Activity and
>   Application.

And from [the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html):

> It allows access to
>   application-specific resources and
>   classes, as well as up-calls for
>   application-level operations such as
>   launching activities, broadcasting and
>   receiving intents, etc.

Typically each Activity will have it's own Context and the Application itself will have a Context.

Comment: I don't really understand reading the article. what condition could cause memory leakage?

Comment: The article as a whole is not relevent, merely the part I highlighted indicating how a Context is used and how each app usually has 2 kinds of Context - Activity Context and Application Context